# Is it possible to integrate Lua to Delphi and run on windows phone

Tags: delphi, lua

I have a Mac app needs to migrate to windows. The app was created using objc and Lua.

I use Delphi to develop app for Windows.

Is it possible to integrate Lua to Delphi in and develop for windows phone7?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Comment: Any comment welcome? Well, I hope you're still merely investigating possibilities, and you did not make any promises to a client about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 is not possible now, and is not likely to be possible in the near future, using Delphi, or even with Delphi Prism. Key elements of Microsoft's WP7 SDK are limited to the two current .NET core languages (C# and Vb.net).  If Microsoft decided to help out remObjects a little bit, then a delphi Prism targetting Windows Phone 7 could become a possibility, but that is out of RemObject's hands, and its unlikely that Microsoft will be interested in helping them join in on the WP7 platform. Perhaps with sufficient engineering dollars, someone could figure out a way to force their way into the WP7 SDK.

Lua is a pretty simple C library, and it should be possible to put it into a DLL and load it into your delphi program.  You could write your application in windows, with delphi, and use LUA scripting, and if you find a .NET "lua interpreter", like [LUA.net](http://www.lua.inf.puc-rio.br/luanet/), you might investigate integrating that into a WP7 app that you wrote entirely in C#.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your first question, **YES** you can use Lua in Delphi.  *Simon J. Stuart* has an incredible blog/website where he has created a number of really useful stuff for Delphi developers.  His [Lua4Delphi](http://www.simonjstuart.com/lua-projects/lua4delphi/) suite will help you integrate Lua scripting into your Windows application.  Go to: http://www.lakraven.com/ or http://www.simonjstuart.com to check out the rest of Simon's stuff ... highly recommended!

With regards to the second part of your question (writing a Delphi app for WP7), that would be **NO** ... you're out of luck there (as Mason mentioned above).

Answer (score 3):

[It's definitely possible to integrate Lua with Delphi](http://tinyurl.com/3au7vju), but good luck getting it to run on Windows Phone 7.  WP7 will only run apps built in the Silverlight or XNA frameworks.

Comment: +1) `Windows Phone7`: a ridiculously restrictive and closed platform that forces you to use SilverLight. `Silverlight`: a Microsoft technology that Microsoft already dropped on all other platforms.  Just be careful when you bet your money on these horses.

Comment: When a Windows Phone (formerly known as Windows CE) device sells a million phones, I'll be impressed. I haven't even SEEN ONE on my daily commute to work, on subways and busses around my city.  It seems that 90% of the working stiffs have iPhones, and the rest that don't have iPhones, have Blackberries.

Comment: Don't forget fools like me who bought an Android phone because of the platform openness, but were heavily disappointed by the lack of timely firmware updates to fix bugs, and lack of awesome development tools.